# How to make it clear that a column of numbers is a link/clickable?

Tags: website-design, web-app, tables, hyperlinks

I have a column in a table that shows a list of "members" and their "item" count (I'm using abstract terms here). The purpose of this table is to show the members with the most items and allow the user to view each member's items.

[image: member-list]

From an interaction perspective, it makes sense to link the `Items` column since users will view a member's items. I don't think linking the `Member` column to go to the member's items makes senses (rather it would link to their membership page such as their "profile").

The issue that I'm encountering is that the number in the `Items` column is usually small and therefore has a very small click target/is not immediately obvious that it's clickable.

Here are some alternates that I've created. I'm still not convinced that they look/feel better.

#### Alternate 1 - a dedicated "view items" link

[image: dedicated 'view items' link]

This design feels weird *not* linking the actual number.

#### Alternate 2 - repeat the "items" text

[image: repeat the 'items' text]

This design is a little weird because in reality the "items" is longer (e.g. such as "viewed items").

---

How can I make it clear that the `Items` column is clickable in this table?

Comment: Are there other columns? If there aren't other columns then it's more of a list and the whole row should be a button. What does the link do? Open a new page, change current page, etc.?

Comment: @moot there are no other columns. The link takes you to a new page. Why should the whole row be a button (buttons does something, links take you somewhere)?

Answer (score 1):

Add a dotted line or underline will make it more obvious & simple. Also try to change the text color to app link color.

[image]

Comment: The number *already is* the app link color. Upon hover, it's slightly darker and underline to indicate possible interaction.

Comment: Underlining upfront is the best way to show it is clickable without any doubt. With this approach you can avoid confusion between row wise & column wise click state. I used this approach in lot of enterprise products, no user complained about it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the screen you have shown, you should show the numbers in colour which is used for CTA's or hyperlinks. It will definitely make user clear that the numbers are clickable.

Also, you can use the wording as "23 Items" on this screen, and when you redirect you can categorize or give the complete description as of "Viewed" or "Saved items" or whatever it is.

Also you can give a tooltip on hover near and on the number that displays a message "Click to see the details".